# Excel Persistent Window

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to display a form invoked from a button within Excel like a messagebox i.e. always on top and persistent until it is dismissed.

So, far I am using

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.TopMost=true;
```

This only keeps the window on top but user could still click around the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it: `frm.ShowDialog();`